# How to get all eligible role assignments from PIM in Azure with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I could not figure out how to get all AAD roles including their eligible users using Powershell. I would like to check regularly if all assignments are correct.

In a few words I am looking for what you can do manually in the portal under `Privileged Identity Management | Azuer AD roles --> Manage --> Roles --> Export Function`

But only via Powershell

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> To get all AAD roles including their eligible users using PowerShell:

Thanks to @[thesysadminchannel](https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-pim-role-assignment-status-for-azure-ad-using-powershell/), By referring to this article, we can get all AAD roles including their eligible users and PIM Assignment Status.

I have made a few changes in the portion of the **`param`** code block and execute the `Begin & Process` procedure calls in the same manner as mentioned in that article.

I have taken a few roles to validate initially as shown in the code below:

***Code Changes:***

```
 param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ParameterSetName = 'User',
            Position  = 0
        )]
        [string[]]  $UserPrincipalName,
            [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ParameterSetName = 'Role',
            Position  = 1
        )]
        [Alias('DisplayNameAs')]
        [ValidateSet(
            'Application Administrator',
            'Application Developer',
            'Attack Simulation Administrator',
            'User Administrator'
        )]
```

[image]
[image]

If you want to retrieve *"**`role assignments only`**"*, you can simply run this command and get the role assignment details:

```
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "*tenantID*" //tenantID of AzureAD
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles?source=recommendations#retrieving-role-assignments)

[image]

**Note**: You need to ***"Run as administrator"*** if you are working with *Windows PowerShell ISE*

Comment: What about getting Azure roles, not Azure AD roles?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding listing the users who are in the `Privileged Identity Management` > `Eligible Assignments` area of an AAD group, you can pull back their info with something like this:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Identity.Governance

$permissionsRequired = (@(
    'Get-MgUser',
    'Get-MgBetaIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupEligibilitySchedule'
) | Find-MgGraphCommand).Permissions.Name | Sort-Object -Unique

# this will open a browser to prompt you to log in
# if you don't have access already this will create a request for the relevant permissions
# if you do, it will log you in with those rights
Connect-MgGraph -Scope $permissionsRequired -ErrorAction Stop

$groupId = 'abcdef01-2345-6789-abcd-ef012345678' # the group whose members we want

$members = Get-MgBetaIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupEligibilitySchedule -Filter "groupId eq '$groupId'"

foreach ($member in $members) {
    Get-MgUser -UserId $member.PrincipalId -Property Id, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, AccountEnabled
}
```

Note: this uses the Beta version of the MS Graph API.
I've shared this version as the alternate approach will be deprecated with in the next year.
Additional information on deprecation [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/important-azure-ad-graph-retirement-and-powershell-module/ba-p/3848270).

Comment: it should be - (($permissionsRequired | Find-MgGraphCommand).permissions.name) | sort-object -unique

Comment: @shadowz1337 I'm not sure I follow?  `$permissionsRequired` is set to the ordered unique set of permissions; not to the commands themselves (note that the assignment is multi-line/includes the pipeline after the array of commands)

Comment: If I run the code you posted, it'll error in Powershell because it's structured incorrectly. I tweaked it and it works fine like this:

https://pastebin.com/zBVSv3dY

Comment: Ah - one of the open parenthesis was missing... corrected - thanks for flagging.